# Did I use memcpy wrong?

Tags: c, memcpy

in the following snippet I wish the function accept a double pointer(2D array) which can be in any data type(in this case, integer), and use memcpy to copy one element at a time of the array to another variable. It passed the compiler but still shows an access violation.

I looked everywhere around the forum but still can't get this right.

Any tips are appreciated. I am nearly devastated by the complexity of C.

```
void ShowImg(void **ptr, IplImage *sample, char window_name[])
{
    int value;
    IplImage *sml_img= cvCreateImage(cvSize(sample->width,sample->height),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
    for(int j=0; j<sample->height; j++)
        for(int i=0; i<sample->width; i++){
            memcpy(&value, ptr+i*sizeof(int)+j*sample->width*sizeof(int), sizeof(int));
            ((uchar *)(sml_img->imageData + sml_img->widthStep*j))[i] = value;
            printf("%d,%d\n", i, j);
        }
    cvNamedWindow(window_name);
    cvShowImage(window_name, sml_img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvDestroyWindow(window_name);
    cvReleaseImage(&sml_img);

}
```

Comment: If you want to assign something to `value`, why don't you just use assignment?

Comment: Because I wish the function to be more general, so I pass a 'void **' pointer to the function. Thus I can assign any data type without rewriting the code very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's a mistake here: `ptr+i*sizeof(int)` since `ptr` is of type `void**` ptr+1 is the next element, meaning `ptr+sizeof(void*)`, why would you multiply it by sizeof(int)?

for example:

```
ptr = 0x00000000, 
sizeof(void*) = 4, 
sizeof(int) = 4
||
\/
ptr+1 = 0x00000004. 
ptr+1*sizeof(int) = 0x00000010.
```

and I don't think that's what you want. (the same about `j*sample->width*sizeof(int)`)

Comment: How can the compiler know the memory location of 'ptr+1'? It's a void type. Since in this case 'ptr' is actually a 2D int array, so I increment 4 byte each time I access an element. If it's a double, I would increment 8 bytes.

Comment: The compiler knows the type of the variable (in your case `void**`) since it is declared (in the function arguments in this case). So it knows that each time you add X to the pointer, to add x * sizeof(void*) to the pointer. this is pointer arithmetic. (see more here: http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/pointer.html)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know void* is of size 4 bytes. Seems the problem is solved.

Comment: Well; void* is the size of an adress. On a 32 bit computer that is 4 bytes, on a 64 bit computer that is 8 bytes.

Comment: @user422005 - due to earlier arguments here regarding pointer size, I didn't even want to get into this :)

Answer (score 1):

`memcpy(3)` is really for copying objects that are larger than the primitive types. You could replace this line:

```
memcpy(&value, ptr+i*sizeof(int)+j*sample->width*sizeof(int), sizeof(int));
```

with this line:

```
value = ptr+i*sizeof(int)+j*sample->width*sizeof(int);
```

The `sizeof(int)` scaling is throwing me; you shouldn't need this if your datatypes are known to the compiler at compile time. Why is your array a `void **` rather than something more specific, which the compiler could work with? (`int **` would be a good first start, but I'm not very good at multidimensional arrays in C, so I'm not positive this would be a better replacement. But I do dislike what you have now. :)